# Need help on how to change a link color once clicked

Tags: html, click

I need help with getting a number text to change color once clicked on.  When I click on the text it goes to a next  html file, but when I return to the main html.  the number is still the same color so Im unable to determine the already visited files. Here is an example of what I've created.

```
                <Center>    <font size="6"><a href="question2.html"><font color="#FFCC00">Taylor</font>
            </td></Center>
            <td bgcolor="#0000CC">

                <Center>    <font size="6"><a href="question3.html"><font color="#FFCC00">Sanders</font>
            </td></Center>
            <td bgcolor="#0000CC">
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend you stop using [style tags](http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/style.html), and [begin using CSS](http://www.csstutorial.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<body link="Orange" vlink="White" alink="Yellow">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#0000CC" align="center">
                <a href="question2.html"><font size="6">Taylor</font></a>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#0000CC" align="center">
                <a href="question3.html"><font size="6">Sanders</font></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the colors for your links:

```
<body link="#FF0000" vlink="#00FF00" alink="#0000FF">
```

But you'll also need to edit your code example too. Remove the <font color="#FFCC00"> tags, which are overriding the browser's default href colors, and add closing tags to your anchors:

```
<font size="6"><a href="question2.html">Taylor</a>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#0000CC">
<font size="6"><a href="question3.html">Sanders</a>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#0000CC">
```

If you want to use <center>, you should move the opening and closing tags inside the <td></td> tags.